# Bluetooth Mesh provisioning using Meshctl: "connect" not working

Tags: bluez, bluetooth-mesh

I am able to provision, configure and control using BlueZ's meshctl tool on Raspberry Pi3. However, after restarting meshctl, or using "disconnect", I am not able to control my device. I tried the "connect" command after restarting meshctl, but it only starts discovery it seems. Is there any way to retain the control after restarting meshctl? Here is a snippet of my logs:

```
[meshctl]# connect 0 0100
Looking for node id 0100 on network with net index 0000
SetDiscoveryFilter success
Discovery started
Adapter property changed 
[CHG] Controller B8:27:EB:46:C1:29 Discovering: yes
```

I am assuming the arguments for connect command are network key index which is 0 and Unicast address of the node to connect to which is 0100.

If it helps, going to onoff menu and trying to control gives the error "Failed to AcquireWrite". And BlueZ version is 5.50.

Thanks in advance!